# Excel Calc Chain

Tags: excel, xml, vba

First question: `r` obviously gives the range, what does `i` stand for?

Second question: it seems that the chain has ordered the calculations by time that I inputted formula into cells? Seems awkward that `calcChain` would calculate say `I1` followed by `I4` followed by `G13` rather than `I10`.

Also it appears that `calcChain` calculates `I13` prior to calculating `I13`'s direct precedents, `$G$13,$E$13,$C$13,$A$13`!

Here is my `calcChain`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<calcChain xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <c r="I1" i="1" l="1"/>
    <c r="I4" i="1"/>
    <c r="I7" i="1"/>
    <c r="I10" i="1"/>
    <c r="I13" i="1"/>
    <c r="G13" i="1"/>
    <c r="E13" i="1"/>
    <c r="C13" i="1"/>
    <c r="A13" i="1"/>
    <c r="A7" i="1"/>
    <c r="E10" i="1"/>
    <c r="C10" i="1"/>
    <c r="A10" i="1"/>
    <c r="G10" i="1"/>
    <c r="C4" i="1"/>
    <c r="C7" i="1" s="1"/>
    <c r="C1" i="1"/>
    <c r="E1" i="1" s="1"/>
    <c r="G1" i="1" s="1"/>
    <c r="A4" i="1"/>
    <c r="E4" i="1" l="1"/>
    <c r="G4" i="1" s="1"/>
    <c r="E7" i="1"/>
    <c r="G7" i="1"/>
</calcChain>
```

Here is my `sheet1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="x14ac"
xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <dimension ref="A1:I13"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="H14" sqref="H14"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="1:9" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A1"><v>3</v></c>
            <c r="C1"><f>A1*5</f><v>15</v></c>
            <c r="E1"><f>C1*2</f><v>30</v></c>
            <c r="G1"><f>E1*3</f><v>90</v></c>
            <c r="I1"><f>G1*2</f><v>180</v></c>
        </row>
        <row r="4" spans="1:9" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A4"><f>A1*5</f><v>15</v></c>
            <c r="C4"><f>A4</f><v>15</v></c>
            <c r="E4"><f>C4*2</f><v>30</v></c>
            <c r="G4"><f>E4*3</f><v>90</v></c>
            <c r="I4"><f>G4*2</f><v>180</v></c>
        </row>
        <row r="7" spans="1:9" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A7"><f>A4*2</f><v>30</v></c>
            <c r="C7"><f>C4*2</f><v>30</v></c>
            <c r="E7"><f>C7+A7</f><v>60</v></c>
            <c r="G7"><f>E7*3</f><v>180</v></c>
            <c r="I7"><f>G7*2</f><v>360</v></c>
        </row>
        <row r="10" spans="1:9" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A10"><f>A7*3</f><v>90</v></c>
            <c r="C10"><f>C7*3</f><v>90</v></c>
            <c r="E10"><f>E7*3</f><v>180</v></c>
            <c r="G10"><f>E10+C10+A10</f><v>360</v></c>
            <c r="I10"><f>G10*2</f><v>720</v></c>
        </row>
        <row r="13" spans="1:9" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="A13"><f>A10*2</f><v>180</v></c>
            <c r="C13"><f>C10*2</f><v>180</v></c>
            <c r="E13"><f>E10*2</f><v>360</v></c>
            <c r="G13"><f>G10*2</f><v>720</v></c>
            <c r="I13"><f>SUM(G13,E13,C13,A13)</f><v>1440</v></c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75"
                 header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-the-calculation-chain. *"The Calculation Chain part specifies the order in which cells in the workbook were last calculated. It only records information about cells containing formulas. It does not include any information about the formula-dependency calculation tree. In other words, the Calculation Chain part does not indicate the dependencies that formulas have on other cell values; it only indicates the order in which the cells were last calculated."*

Comment: *"The index attribute `i` indicates the index of the sheet with which that cell is associated."*